# I need help to modify pnscan

Tags: c, bash, perl, ssh

His currently shows:

```
$ pnscan -s somehost.com 22

50.87.248.227   : box1227.bluehost.com                     :    22 : TXT : SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3\r\n
```

I`m trying to modify pnscan to show me results like this:

```
$ pnscan -s somehost.com 22

50.87.248.227   : somehost.com                     :    22 : TXT : SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3\r\n
```

Here is the code
https://github.com/ptrrkssn/pnscan/blob/master/pnscan.c

```
if (pr_sym)
{
    hep = gethostbyaddr((const char *) &in, sizeof(in), AF_INET);
    fprintf(fp, "%-15s : %-40s : %5d", host,
            inet_ntoa(in), hep ? hep->h_name : "(unknown)", port);
}
else
    fprintf(fp, "%-15s : %5d", inet_ntoa(in), port);
}
```

I tried here to change on the above fprint,but it dosen`t work, because argv[i] is declared after these fprint,i think ?
Can someone help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right that that is the place to change. But it is a tricky to do that. From `main` which has the `argv[]` information, you need to change `r_worker` and `f_worker` which both call `probe`. then `probe` calls function `print_host`.

So you need to pass the value of `argv[2]` all the way from main to print_host. Then you can change the fprintf line you showed.

Comment: Thanks, but now i`m dumber than i was before .. i know too little so i can do what u wrote :D

Comment: to make things easier, but uglier, you can copy argv[2] to a global variable, then use that global inside print_host

Comment: Thanks, but still crashing my brain .. to understand exactly what you said, i need to read the whole C/C++ book .. and i can`t, not enough space for that too .. :D